# Advanced MySQL area costs

Tags: php, mysql

I am a little familar with MySQL but thinking about implementing this feature makes my brain hurt. I need a system where you can set the "cost" of an area say between the coordinates X=20 Y=20 WIDTH=20 HEIGHT=20 at cost of 15 per pixel, now if you place another area within this area, say at X=25, Y=25, WIDTH=10, HEIGHT=10 at cost of 5 per pixel the previous area is broken down into 4 parts and the middle is wiped in favor of this area.

I would also like to be able to calculate the "cost" of an area between certain pixels. Hope I've explained that in a manner most of you will understand. I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Why is the previous area broken down in 4 parts?

Comment: more of a math question than a programming one

Comment: +1 . . . I happen to think it is a very interesting database question.

Comment: +1 to give you some views. If you would add in a possible database schema, that might show people what you are after.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out the schema for quite some time now :(

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this by storing all the areas with a priority and then getting the cost on a pixel by pixel basis.

So, the cost for a single pixel would be:

```
select c.*
from costs c
where PIXELX between c.x and c.x + c.deltax and PIXELY between c.y + c.deltay
order by priority desc
limit 1
```

To extend this to an area of pixels, you would expand the area into a set of pixels.  I would recommend having a `numbers` table to help with this:

```
select x.num as x, y.num as y
from numbers x cross join
     numbers y
where x.num between PIXELX and PIXELX and DELTAX and
      y.num between PIXELY and PIXELY and DELTAY
```

Now, combine these ideas to get all possible costs for a given pixel:

```
select x.num as x, y.num as y, max(priority) as maxpriority
from numbers x cross join
     numbers y join
     costs c
     on x.num between c.x and c.x + c.deltax and y.num between c.y + c.deltay
where x.value between PIXELX and PIXELX and DELTAX and
      y.value between PIXELY and PIXELY and DELTAY
group by x.num, y.num
```

Finally, join the costs in for the given priority:

```
select sum(c.cost)
from (select x.num as x, y.num as y, max(priority) as maxpriority
      from numbers x cross join
           numbers y join
           costs c
           on x.num between c.x and c.x + c.deltax and y.num between c.y + c.deltay
      where x.value between PIXELX and PIXELX and DELTAX and
            y.value between PIXELY and PIXELY and DELTAY
      group by x.num, y.num
    ) xyp join
    costs c
    on  xyp.x between c.x and c.x + c.deltax and xyp.y between c.y + c.deltay and
        xyp.maxpriority = c.priority
```

Comment: IS THIS REAL LIFE. Those are 2 separate tables correct? How will their structure look?

Comment: Anyone? This looks like chinese to me

Answer (score -1):

> thinking about implementing this feature makes my brain hurt

Yeah, mine too! Hmmm... this does sound very familiar though - because it's been done before on the [milliondollarhomepage](http://www.milliondollarhomepage.com/)

Perhaps you could instead use or adapt a pre-made solution such as [Gpix](http://www.tufat.com/script63.htm) or else google "pixel advertising script".

Comment: That is nothing like what I'm looking for.